# wso2 msf4j: How to configure the server properties

Tags: wso2, msf4j

I'm currently trying to use MSF4J with the StreamingOutput API. However, instead of streaming a File, I want to stream a series of unending short strings/texts. I want the strings to be flushed to the client immediately. However, the client is not getting it after the flush. I believe it is due to the default 8kb buffer, because my strings get flushed after a while in chunks. How do I override this default buffer the same way it is done in glassfish? https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#OUTBOUND_CONTENT_LENGTH_BUFFER

I want something like...

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.set("jersey.config.server.contentLength.buffer", 0);**

new MicroservicesRunner()
  .setProperties(properties)**
  .addInterceptor(new HTTPMonitoringInterceptor())
  .deploy(new MyService())
  .start();
```

My streamingout class

```
new StreamingOutput(){    
     public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException, WebApplicationException      {
        while(true){
           os.write("some string".getBytes());
           os.flush();
        }    
      }
}
```

thank you.

Comment: So your strings are get flused immediately but not int values is that the case?

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne, integers are also treated as strings as they are returned via REST. Even with the flush, the client won't receive the strings right away until the 8kb buffer has been consumed.

Comment: Can you share the full service?

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne please see below